# How to pull Google Places info with Rails 3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, google-maps

So I know that google places API serves the place information (name, location, website, type ect) with JSON but I was wondering how to grab the data from the JSON?

Basically I've got a site where users can use the google maps API Ive set up to search for their retail shops and Id like to store all that information in a table so that way when you go to the user's profile page you can see their google place information on a integrated map.

Maybe theres an easier way to do that but Im not sure how.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should only use the google places api from the client.  Google has a rate limit set pretty low, and it's based on IP address (at least for the google maps api).  So if you're making too many requests from your web server, all of a sudden google cuts you off for the day.  The way around this is to just do all the calls in javascript, so it's coming from the users IP address.

When the user types their address into your form, use the google places api to get the place id, or lat/lng coordinates, then save those along with everything else in your database.  Then just use that data to fetch the place json from the google places api when they view the user profile.

**Update**

According to the [google places docs](https://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/places.html#place_details_requests), it's actually the "`reference` token" you want to store, not the `id`.

Since you want users to be able to search for their stores, you need to make 2 queries:

1. First, you need to have lat/lng coordinates to be able to query the places api ([google places api docs](https://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/places.html).  You do this by querying [google maps' geocoding api](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/geocoding/) with, say, the users current location, or some address they filled out when signing up.  The response will return, among other attributes, the lat/lng coordinates.  Save those to your database tied to the user model.  I've done this with [Geocoder](https://github.com/alexreisner/geocoder), but because of google's rate limiting, you quickly run into problems.  Keep all the geocoding stuff client side, then save the results with ajax or whatever.
2. Then, on the page where the user searches for their retail stores, you just query the places api with their lat/lng coordinates: [google places api search request example](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/places.html#place_search_requests).  You'll get a list of results.  For each place the user selects, you save the `reference` token.
3. Then when you want to retrieve the details for that place, you make a [google places api 'place details' request](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/places.html#place_details_requests) using the reference token.

Comment: How do I actually grab that information from the API? I guess I would only store the place id, in the table then right? The place Id should get everything I need tho right?

Comment: Exactly.  Updated the answer.

Comment: Awesome well, do you know how to use rails to pull the place ID from the search result? Im still new to the google API and am trying to figure this out

Comment: The search you're doing is in javascript, so you'll get JSON in response.  Then just use javascript to get the place id.  Then you can save that with `jQuery.ajax` or something similar.  You don't need any Rails here.  The maps api takes a while to get familiar with, just stick with it, do it all in javascript, it's so much more powerful and easier once you get used to it.

Comment: Quick example/hack: paste this into the web inspector console (chrome/safari/firefox), and look for the array of `[▶Object, ▶Object, ...]`, you'll see the JSON, and the place id's and reference tokens: `function callback(results, status) { console.log(results); } ; initialize();` (on this example https://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/place-search.html)

Comment: Hmm OK, I started reading over the V3 API and I think that I should just have the users search with geocoding and then enter in information about their shops which will appear in an [info window](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/overlays.html#InfoWindows). That way if the user doesnt have a google places account they can still have some info show up. One question tho, if my app is storing the latlng and using that with the maps API, will that kill my 100 day limit? I want to make sure I can store the location, but have the client make the request

Comment: what other attributes than id and reference are allowed to be cached for performance serverside ? my Android app shows distance to list entries and fetching the lat/lon and place name for each entry, for every client, doesn't seem to be a good solution.   how often this cache should be cleared or updated ?

Answer (score 1):

I thought of doing the same with Geocoder, i think it's worth looking at.http://railscasts.com/episodes/273-geocoder?view=comments

Comment: Geocoder supports only the Google Maps API, not Google Places.

Answer (score 1):

For using Google Places API with Rails, you can use the Gem google_places:: https://github.com/marceldegraaf/google_places

I hope this will help you.